# Proving if one conditional expression is equal to another conditional expression

Tags: javascript, logic, conditional-statements

How do you go about proving the two following expressions below are equally the same?

```
(A && C) || (B && C)
```

```
(A || B) && C
```

Comment: Loop through all the combinations of values of `A`, `B`, and `C`, and test whether any of them get a different result.

Comment: Sounds like homework. For `n` variables, a brute force approach will take `2^n` iterations. A smart approach would be to treat && like * and || like +, then simplify. If through commutative, associative or distributive properties you can make them equal, then they are equal

Comment: @JamesMcDowell The (unimportant) reason I'm asking is because I want to make my if conditional shorter and easier to read. Each of A, B, and C are simplified versions of really, really long variables

Comment: @JamesMcDowell Yes I assumed `&&` and `||` worked like the distributive property of `*` and `+`. I just wanted confirmation that this is indeed how it worked. I guess this is more of a math problem, really

Answer (score 3):

The proof that `(A && C) || (B && C) ≡ (A || B) && C` is a simple one.

Let's start with the right hand side of the equation and get to the left.

Through the logical distributive law, it can be shown that for all propositions P, Q, and R, `P && (Q || R) ≡ (P && Q) || (P && R)`.
Through the logical commutative law, it can be shown that for all propositions P and Q, `P && Q ≡ Q && P`

Using this, we can show that the above statements are equivalent.
`(A || B) && C ≡ C && (A || B)` (Through the commutative law)
`C && (A || B) ≡ (C && A) || (C && B)` (Through the distributive law)
`(C && A) || (C && B) ≡ (A && C) || (B && C)` (Through the commutative law)
Therefore, we have that `(A && C) || (B && C) ≡ (A || B) && C`

Answer (score 0):

The evidence that `(A && C) || (B && C) ≡ (A || B) && C` is a simple one.

Let's start with a list of all possible permutations, then test them.

```js
const permutations = [
  [false, false, false],
  [false, false, true],
  [false, true, false],
  [false, true, true],
  [true, false, false],
  [true, false, true],
  [true, true, false],
  [true, true, true],
];

permutations.forEach(permutation => {
  const [A, B, C] = permutation;
  console.log(((A && C) || (B && C)) === ((A || B) && C));
});
```

Comment: Nice programmatic approach for this case, but you have many duplicates in your `permutations` array! We have 3 variables, so the number of permutations should be 2^3 = 8 permutations.